# Get the max date time in a table with multiple entries for each date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I have a table that has

```
Location | IsBroken | Date
AZ          1         2019-01-01 12:00
CA          0         2019-01-01 12:00
NY          1         2019-01-01 12:00
AZ          1         2019-01-01 15:00
CA          0         2019-01-01 15:00
NY          1         2019-01-01 15:00
AZ          1         2019-01-01 19:00
CA          0         2019-01-01 19:00
NY          1         2019-01-01 19:00
AZ          1         2019-01-02 14:00
CA          0         2019-01-02 14:00
NY          1         2019-01-02 14:00
AZ          1         2019-01-02 16:00
CA          0         2019-01-02 16:00
NY          1         2019-01-02 16:00
AZ          1         2019-01-03 12:00
CA          0         2019-01-03 12:00
NY          1         2019-01-03 12:00
AZ          1         2019-01-03 17:00
CA          0         2019-01-03 17:00
NY          1         2019-01-03 17:00
```

And I only want one row per date, preferably the max, so the result should be

```
AZ          1         2019-01-01 19:00
CA          0         2019-01-01 19:00
NY          1         2019-01-01 19:00
AZ          1         2019-01-02 16:00
CA          0         2019-01-02 16:00
NY          1         2019-01-02 16:00
AZ          1         2019-01-03 17:00
CA          0         2019-01-03 17:00
NY          1         2019-01-03 17:00
```

I've tried using a nested query in where:

```
WHERE foo.Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM foo)
```

but it only gives me back 1 row.

The table will have continuous dates also, like

```
2019-01-02 
2019-01-03
```

etc.

And I need results for each date.

Comment: Visualize, Is `2019-01-01 19:00` is typo on all rows or you intentionally need it?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I just what the max date time for every date. So I forgot to include in the initial post that it the whole table will multiple entries on the same date, but I need the entry for the entry with the largest time for each day. So the query can't only obtain rows for 2019-01-01, it needs to obtain for 2019-01-02, 2019-01-03 and so on

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use corelated subquery

```
select t1.* from table_name t1
where t1.date= ( select max(date) from table_name t2 where t1.location=te.location and t1.date=t2.date)
```

you can do it using row_number() if your dbms support

```
select * from (select *,row_number()over(partition by location,Date order by date desc) rn
from table_name
) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks, that brought be closer to what I needed. I forgot to mention that the table is full of dates for the whole year, and this only only got me the latest date. How would I do it so I only get 1 row per date per location.

Comment: @Visualize share sample data for that and expected output

Comment: just updated my original post with a complete example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where [Location] = t.[Location] 
    and convert(date, [Date]) = convert(date, t.[Date])
    and [Date] > t.[Date]
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e8bccff01782838b5e0309adfef9a788).
Results:

```
> Location | IsBroken | Date               
> :------- | -------: | :------------------
> AZ       |        1 | 01/01/2019 19:00:00
> CA       |        0 | 01/01/2019 19:00:00
> NY       |        1 | 01/01/2019 19:00:00
> AZ       |        1 | 02/01/2019 16:00:00
> CA       |        0 | 02/01/2019 16:00:00
> NY       |        1 | 02/01/2019 16:00:00
> AZ       |        1 | 03/01/2019 17:00:00
> CA       |        0 | 03/01/2019 17:00:00
> NY       |        1 | 03/01/2019 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT location, MAX(Date) 
FROM foo
GROUP BY location
```

Should give you what you want I think, but w/o the isBlocked if it has different values, because then you will need to add it to the group by statement which will make it more rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from locations_table t
where t.col_date = (select max(col_date)
                    from locations_table)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d7980749ef54e6445349867eaa5379f7)